# Jquery masonry Infinite scroll appended

Tags: jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am using jquery masonry in angularjs with infinite scroll, its working good. Only the problem is I want to append masonry to next element and and currently it is getting applied to all items. I come through the method appended, but as I am using masonry infinite scroll its not giving me how to do that.
consider code:

```
<div infinite-scroll='items.nextPage()' infinite-scroll-disabled='items.busy' infinite-scroll-distance='1'>
    <div class="tiles" ng-repeat="item in items.item" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
        <div>
            <img ng-src="{{item.url}}" alt="{{item.itemName}}" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent){
    var $container = $('#masonry-tiles').masonry({
        //TODO: Once the way to implement the width classes to the masonry divs is figured out the columnWidth will be changed from 66 to grid-sizer
        columnWidth: 150,
        itemSelector: '.tiles'
    });
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {

        console.log('All images load');
        if($rootScope.infiniteScroll){

            console.log('Second time');
            $container.masonry('prepended');
        }else{

            console.log('First Time');
            $container.masonry();
        }
    });
});
```

and to append next elements I am using normal blogs to implement. Any suggestion.
Thanks.